# Goroutines broke the program

Tags: go, goroutine

The problem is this: There is a web server. I figured that it would be beneficial to use goroutines in page loading, so I went ahead and did: called loadPage function as a goroutine. However, when doing this, the server simply stops working without errors. It prints a blank, white page. The problem has to be in the function itself- something there is conflicting with the goroutine somehow.

These are the relevant functions:

```
func loadPage(w http.ResponseWriter, path string) {
   s := GetFileContent(path)
   w.Header().Add("Content-Type", getHeader(path))
   w.Header().Add("Content-Length", GetContentLength(path))
   fmt.Fprint(w, s)
}
func GetFileContent(path string) string {
   cont, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
   e(err)
   aob := len(cont)
   s := string(cont[:aob])
   return s
}


func GetFileContent(path string) string {
   cont, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
   e(err)
   aob := len(cont)
   s := string(cont[:aob])
   return s
}

func getHeader(path string) string {
   images := []string{".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png"}
   readable := []string{".htm", ".html", ".php", ".asp", ".js", ".css"}
   if ArrayContainsSuffix(images, path) {
      return "image/jpeg"
   }
   if ArrayContainsSuffix(readable, path) {
      return "text/html"
   }
   return "file/downloadable"
}


func ArrayContainsSuffix(arr []string, c string) bool {
   length := len(arr)
   for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
      s := arr[i]
      if strings.HasSuffix(c, s) {
         return true
      }
   }
return false
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with these functions. Goroutines are like daemon threads, if the main goroutine exits, all current goroutines are killed without finishing. Check to make sure your main goroutine doesn't exit before this one finishes.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good thing to check for. Additionally, have you tried seeing what happens when you don't run them concurrently? Does everything work properly? It may be that the issue isn't actually with running things in goroutines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this happens is because your [HandlerFunc](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) which calls "loadPage" is called synchronously with the request. When you call it in a go routine the Handler is actually returning immediately, causing the response to be sent immediately. That's why you get a blank page.

You can see this in [server.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/server.go#L1096) (line 1096):

```
serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
if c.hijacked() {
    return
}
w.finishRequest()
```

The `ServeHTTP` function calls your handler, and as soon as it returns it calls "finishRequest". So your Handler function must block as long as it wants to fulfill the request.

Using a go routine will actually not make your page any faster. Synchronizing a singe go routine with a channel, as Philip suggests, will also not help you in this case as that would be the same as not having the go routine at all.

The root of your problem is actually `ioutil.ReadFile`, which buffers the entire file into memory before sending it.

If you want to stream the file you need to use `os.Open`. You can use `io.Copy` to stream the contents of the file to the browser, which will used chunked encoding.

That would look something like this:

```
f, err := os.Open(path)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, "Not Found", http.StatusNotFound)
    return
}
n, err := io.Copy(w, f)
if n == 0 && err != nil {
    http.Error(w, "Error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
```

If for some reason you need to do work in multiple go routines, take a look at `sync.WaitGroup`. Channels can also work.

If you are trying to just serve a file, there are other options that are optimized for this, such as [FileServer](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) or [ServeFile](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile).

Comment: This is a good response, thank you. Good clarification.. the reason we did things like this (ie readfile etc) is because we basically just started this project to learn golang so it definitely isn't done in the best possible way. Thank you!

Comment: @Arcticcu In that case I highly recommend reading the source code of the built-in packages. Also look for any files that end in "_test.go" for examples when the docs don't help.

Answer (score 0):

In the typical web framework implementations in Go, the route handlers are invoked as Goroutines.  I.e. at some point the web framework will say `go loadPage(...)`.

So if you call a Go routine from *inside* `loadPage`, you have *two* levels of Goroutines.

The Go scheduler is really lazy and will not execute the second level if it's not forced to. So you need to enforce it through synchronization events.  E.g. by using channels or the `sync` package.  Example:

```
func loadPage(w http.ResponseWriter, path string) {
  s := make(chan string)
  go GetFileContent(path, s)
  fmt.Fprint(w, <-s)
}
```

The [Go documentation](http://golang.org/ref/mem) says this:

> If the effects of a goroutine must be observed by another goroutine,
>   use a synchronization mechanism such as a lock or channel
>   communication to establish a relative ordering.

Why is this actually a smart thing to do?  In larger projects you may deal with a large number of Goroutines that need to be coordinated somehow efficiently.  So why call a Goroutine if it's output is used nowhere?  A fun fact: I/O operations like `fmt.Printf` do trigger synchronization events too.